# insert data into hasone table from a form input in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have two table one is user which is parent and other is posts(child) table and its coulmns are

```
 public function up(){
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('body');
            $table->timestamps();

        }
   }
```

i have already specified

`$this->hasOne('Post');`

relation into user model. now i want to insert data into posts table where with form i can save data into title and body column into there respective id's.

Answer (score 3):

If it's an authenticated user, you can do this:

```
auth()->user()->posts()->create($request->all());
```

To make `create()` method work you also need to have `$fillable` array with all properties in the `Post` model:

```
$protected fillable = ['title', 'body'];
```